# Trying to set context and it's not an enclosing class. Ideas? :)

Tags: java, android, android-context, declare

***Problem I'm having:***

- 4th line down I get an error saying
  "com.example.wifilocator.MainActivity" is not an enclosing class

***Code in question(From MainActivity) - 4th line:***

```
class wifi {
    int signalStrength = 0;
    int loopToggle = 0;
    Context context = MainActivity.this;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    public void loop() throws InterruptedException {
        while (loopToggle == 0) {
            WifiManager signalStrength = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            String wifiInfo = WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_INFO;
            TextView textView = (TextView) textView.findViewById(R.id.readOut);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

***Thanks so much for any help! :)***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you're placing the `wifi` outside the `MainActivity` class like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  ...
}

class wifi {
  ...
}
```

`wifi` class **must be inside** the `MainActivity` class, like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  ...

  class wifi {
     ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line  `Context context = MainActivity.this;` make no sence unless it's inside `MainActivity`, try something like this instead :

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    public void loop(Context context) throws InterruptedException {
        while (loopToggle == 0) {
            WifiManager signalStrength = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            String wifiInfo = WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_INFO;
            TextView textView = (TextView) textView.findViewById(R.id.readOut); //this line makes no sence too
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

And call it from your `MainActivity` like this :

```
loop(MainActivity.this);
```

Hope this helps